# Reading InputStream from Java Interactive Process using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, inputstream, interactive, processbuilder

I am trying to run an interactive executable from Java application using ProcessBuilder; it's supposed to take input, produce output and then wait for the next input. The main problem here with Input/Output streams. I send an input and get nothing. Here is the code:

```
private static Process process;
private static BufferedReader result;
private static PrintWriter input;

process = new ProcessBuilder("compile-lm", lmFile.toString(), " --score yes").redirectErrorStream(true).start();

input = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()), true);
input.println(message);
System.out.println(message);

result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line = new String();

while ((line = result.readLine()) != null)
{

/* Some processing for the read line */

System.out.println("output:\t" + line);
}
```

Comment: if you have an exit status try to get it by using `int es=process.waitFor();` and displaying it to se what is the problem

Comment: @ZiedJaballah I tried to get the exit status after the right operation 'input.println(message)' and it was 0 "normal termination". Is there anything else i can try to investigate where is the problem?

Comment: try to change the command. the code sounds clean. maybe you are not getting an output just because the commande returns nothing.

Comment: I figured out that ProcessBuilder runs the command once and then closes the executable although it has to be running (interactive). That's why I didn't get any results because it's shutdown.

Could you advise what else to try?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code it works fine  there is no problem with the code. I think that the problem with the command that you are trying to execute ( it returns nothing ). try to change parameters or even change the entire command to test. and if you can execute the comand in other place ( terminal for example try it and see the output with the same parameters  )

Answer (score 0):

I have used a similar setup many times over but can not find a working copy right now :( My first instinct though is to move the line where you initialise the reader (result variable) to before the one where you send the command out to the process (input.println(message)).

Comment: Why would that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the output stream to the process. Basically you're at the mercy of whatever buffering is happening in the output side of the child process.